# How to associate users with posts in django and display data based on which user signed in?

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in django:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.utils import timezone


class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ingredients = models.TextField(max_length=200,help_text="Put the ingredients required$")
    instructions = models.TextField(max_length=500)



    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import RecipeForm

def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:url'))
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Error")

    return render(request, 'page.html', {'form': RecipeForm()})
```

Does anyone know how do I associate a user id with it so that when it is saved in database, it also saves which user made this recipe and when a user logs in, he is able to see his recipes only and not the recipes saved by other users. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, give it a foreign key. [Page 2 of the official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/)

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `ForeignKey` field, pointing to the built-in `User` model, in your `Recipe` model:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='recipes')
```

this field will contain the `id` of the user who created the recipe.

**EDIT**

And if you have an `user` object you can access all its `recipes` like this:

```
user.recipes.all()
```

and you'll get only the recipes of that user.

Comment: but how can i show user only his recipes when displaying the list? is there any filter i need to insert in model?